# Segmentation fault when indexing into char array via pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

My code is causing a segmentation fault when accessing an array element even though that element was already accessed without a problem.

```
int charToInt(char a)
{
    int b;
    if(isdigit(a))
    {   
        b = a - '0' - 1;
    }
    if(isalpha(a))
    {
        b = a - 65; 
    }
    return b;   
}

int validPosition(char **array, int r, int c, char* position, int slots)
{
    int i,k;
    if(strlen(position) == 5)
    {
        if(!isalpha(position[0]) || !isdigit(position[1]) || position[2]!=' ' || (position[3]!='N' && position[3]!='E' && position[3]!='W' && position[3]!='S')) //lathos gramma
        {
            printf("\n%s", "Invalid answear.This is an example of a valid answear: A5 N");
            return 2;
        }
        if( charToInt(position[0]) > r - 1 || charToInt(position[1]) > c - 1  )//ama vgainei eksw apo ta oria
        {
            printf("\n%s", "The position you choosed is out of the bountries...");
            return 2;
        }
        printf("\n%s%c%s","position[3] is: ",position[3], " but it doesn't work >_<"); // position[3] is N 
        if(position[3] == 'N') //the problem is here <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<
        {
            printf("\n%s", "come on");
            if(charToInt(position[0]) + slots < r)
            {
                for(i=charToInt(position[0])-1; i<charToInt(position[0])+slots; i++)
                {
                     if(array[i-1][charToInt(position[1])-1] != '.')
                     {
                         printf("\n%s", "The position you choosed is not valid because there is oneother ship there");
                         return 2;
                     }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n%s", "The ship is going out of the bountries...");
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `position` holds the string `"A9 N"`, the `printf` correctly outputs `'N'` for `position[3]`. For some reason when it tries to do `if(position[3] == 'N')`, however, a segmentation fault occurs.

Example program run:

```
Example of positioning: G3 E

Aircraft carrier (5 places), Give location and direction: A9 N

1

position[3] is: N but it doesn't work >_<
```

Comment: The problem may not be where you think it is, stdout may just not have flushed when it crashes. This is why `printf("\n%s", "come on");` doesn't appear to run. How is this function called? How are its parameters obtained? What does the definition of `charToInt` look like? My guess is the problem is actually related to the access to `array` instead of `position`.

Comment: Your array indexing is pretty shaky and so is your for-loop. Just gotta hope that your `i` variable provides a nice little value that is bigger or equal to `1`, otherwise you are in deep drouble with your code.

Comment: array is a 2d array and it contains characters(created with malloc).r and c are 9 and 9 in the specific example(rows columns). slots=5. i created char position[10] in the function that called this function and with  fgets(position, 10, stdin); i putted A9 N inside it. int charToInt(char a) and for example: for a='A' it returns 0. for a='9' it returns 8 (the returns are -1 because i am trying to create a game and the user sees 1 2 3 4...instead of 0 1 2 3 4..

Comment: Your `charToInt` function, how does that look? (There is a stdlib function otherwise called `atoi` which stands for ascii to int).

Comment: @sneakylittlefellow Yeah so if you put in `A` as `position[0]`, then `charToInt(position[0])` will return `0`. So first run in the for loop makes `i = 0 - 1 equaling that i == -1` and for that loop you try to access `array[i - 1]; <-- BAM error`. Cant access array[-2], thats a negative array index and is not allowed.

Comment: Yes I just tested again with your code real quick and it is as I said, really shaky and wrong. Please rethink your logic of what you want to do and make sure that you never are able to access array indexes that are out of bounds or your programs _will_ crash. If you take input during runtime well then it's even more important to check it and have error handling. Not fun that the game crashes when someone spent 2 hours playing it and mistypes their final move and game dies. People can get upset for less ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on your updates, it seems you have a variety of problems. For future reference, actually adding in the (possibly simplified) code showing how you were calling the function in question is better than trying to describe it using prose in a comment. There will be less guesswork for the people trying to help you.

If I'm reading your comment correctly, the code that calls `validPosition` looks something like this:

```
// "r and c are 9 and 9 in the specific example(rows columns)."
int rows = 9;
int columns = 9;

// "slots=5."
int slots = 5;

// "array is a 2d array and it contains characters(created with malloc)."
char **array = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(char));

// "i created char position[10] in the function that called this function"
char position[10];
// "and with fgets(position, 10, stdin); i putted A9 N inside it."
fgets(position, 10, stdin);

validPosition(array, rows, columns, position, slots);
```

The first problem is your description of the allocation of array (I apologize if I misunderstood your comment and this isn't actually what you are doing). It should look similar to the code below for a dynamically sized two-dimensional array used with two subscripting operations (`array[index1][index2]`, as it is in `validPosition`). Pointers-to-pointers (`char **array`) act differently than fixed sized multi-dimensional arrays (`array[SIZE1][SIZE2]`) when you access them that way.

```
// each entry in array should be a pointer to an array of char
char **array = malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
```

You also need to be careful about using position after the `fgets` call. You should check the return value to make sure it isn't `NULL` (indicating an `EOF` or error condition). The string may not be `\0`-terminated in this case. In fact, all the elements may still be uninitialized (assuming you didn't initialized them before the call). This can lead to undefined behavior.

The next issue is that `validPosition` does not return a value on every code path. One example is if `strlen(position) != 5`. The other is if you enter the `for` loop and `array[i-1][charToInt(position[1])-1] != '.'` is never true (that is, the ship placement is deemed valid).

As strange as it is for an English speaker to say this to a Greek author, lets ignore internationalization and focus only on the default C local. The checks on position[0] should therefore be sufficient, though you might consider allowing your users to use lowercase letters as well. When converting `position[1]` from `1`-based to `0`-based, however, you do not account for the case when it is `'0'`, which will result in `charToInt` returning `-1`. Furthermore, you're erroneously doing the subtraction again in the second array subscript of `array[i-1][charToInt(position[1])-1]`.

Similarly, as pointed out by Jite and BLUEPIXY, you are doing *two* extra subtractions on the result of `charToInt(position[0])`: one in the for loop initializer (`i=charToInt(position[0])-1`) and one in the first array subscript of `array[i-1][charToInt(position[1])-1]`.

Once you fix that, you might find that you are sometimes incorrectly telling the user that their selection is invalid. This is because you are checking `charToInt(position[0]) + slots < r` instead of `<= r`.

As I mentioned in my comment, one of the accesses to `array` is very probably the culprit behind your segmentation violation, not `position[3] == 'N'`. The reason you don't see the output of `printf("\n%s", "come on");` is that your `stdout` appears to be line-buffered and there's no end of line to flush it. It is generally automatically flushed on *normal* program termination, however you're seg-faulting so that doesn't happen.

Finally, these are only the semantic errors I noticed. Stylistically, the code could also stand to be improved. For instance, it seems you're going to be implementing `else if(position[3] == 'E'`, `else if(position[3] == 'W'`, and `else if(position[3] == 'S'` clauses with similar logic to your `if(position[3] == 'N'` clause. This increases the likelihood you'll introduce an error by incorrectly copying-and-pasting and also increases your work later when you need to make a change in four places instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the terminology 'Segmentation Fault' I believe you are on Linux machine.
Use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to find the cause of error. Here are the steps.

1. Compile with additional -g flag (ex. gcc -g my_prog.c)
2. Run debugger: gdb a.out
3. Use 'list' command to find the line for break point (eg. first line of your function)
4. Set breakpoint on that line with: b 25 (if 25 is that line)
5. Run program with 'run' command
6. Use command 'next' to execute next line of code

Now the execution will pause on that line, you can examine memory, print variable contents
and stuff. But generally you want to determine on which line the execution fails and what was in which variable.

With a little playing with memory, you will easily find where the problem is. Personally, my code wont work with gdb support.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps segmentation fault at `array[i-1][charToInt(position[1])-1]`

i:`charToInt(position[0])-1` : charToInt('A') - 1 : -1 <- Array out-of-bounds